# How to access the specific array data after parsing the json file?

Tags: swift

Here is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "District_en": "Kowloon City",
    "Name_en": "Carpenter Road Park",
    "GIHS": "9G5i7NFpXL",
    "Court_no_en": "4",
    "Court_no_cn": "4"
  },
  {
    "District_en": "Kowl",
    "Name_en": "Road Park",
    "GIHS": "9G5i7NFaXL",
    "Court_no_en": "5",
    "Court_no_cn": "6"
  }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
func loadjson() {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "court", withExtension: "json"){
            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsondata = try decoder.decode([Court].self, from: data)
                print(jsondata)
                } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
}
```

I have a localized JSON file which I know how to parse the file, but after parsing the file, I don't know how to access the specific array data inside.

Comment: That's very basic stuff. Please read [Swift Language Guide: Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) and [Swift Language Guide: Structs and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: please add the Court struct or model you are using

Answer (score 1):

When you obtain json data you need to convert it into your model Court. Court should have a special initializer that converts json data into model's properties. Like this:

```
struct Court: Codable {
   var district: String
   var name: String
   // and so on

   init?(json: [String: Any]) {
      guard let district = json["District_en"] as? String,
           let name = json["Name_en"] as? String else {
           return nil
       }

       self.district = district
       self.name = name
   }
}
```

Then you can get your models from json data:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

if let json = jsonData as? [[String: Any]] {
      let array = json.compactMap(Court.init)

      print(array)
}
// Prints: [Court(district: "Kowloon City", name: "Carpenter Road Park"), Court(district: "Kowl", name: "Road Park")]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i cannot cast the data to dictionary, Cast from '[Court]' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always fails.I am trying to solve this now

Comment: I changed the Court's initializer above. Check it now.

If initializer has parameter [String: Any], you should cast Any type to String explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem as below, please take a reference, by using modeling and keyword self.

struct Court : Codable {

```
let addressCn : String?
let openingHoursCn : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case addressCn = "Address_cn"
    case openingHoursCn = "Opening_hours_cn"

}
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    addressCn = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .addressCn)
    openingHoursCn = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey:.openingHoursCn)
}
```

class TableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var court = [Court]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchjson()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection    section: Int) -> Int {
    return court.count
}


func fetchjson() {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "facility-bkbc", withExtension: "json"){
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            self.court = try decoder.decode([Court].self, from: data)
            print(court)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }catch{ print(error)}}}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

It's like any other type of array.
For example:

```
if let decodedData = jsonData{
    print(decodedData.first)

    print(decodedData[1].name)
}
```

In the first print you will get the "Carpenter Road Park" object printed.
In the second case it will print: "Road Park" (supposing you decoded "Name_en" as "name".